# Translate Python to Lua: replace a string character in a list

Tags: python, string, replace, lua

I'm learning Lua and I have some knowledge of python and I want to replace a character in a string just like in python but I didn't get lucky to find the exact translation functions.

I want to make this in Lua:

```
l = ["#01","#02", "#03"]
print(l)

for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=l[i].replace("#","")
    #print (i)

print (l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in Python you would use a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = ["#01", "#02", "#03", "04"]
>>> l = [s.replace('#', '') for s in l]
>>> print(l)
['01', '02', '03', '04']
```

If you really need to update the list in place:

```
>>> l[:] = [s.replace('#', '') for s in l]
```

In Lua you can iterate over the list/array/table with [`for`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ForTutorial) and use [`gsub`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) to replace the substrings:

```
> l = {"#01", "#02", "#03", "04"}
> for k, v in pairs(l) do print(k, v) end
1   #01
2   #02
3   #03
4   04

> for k in next,l do l[k] = l[k]:gsub("#", "") end
> for k, v in pairs(l) do print(k, v) end
1   01
2   02
3   03
4   04
```

Comment: `nil` is redundant after `next`

Answer (score 1):

Analog of `string.gsub()` but without magic characters (plain replacement)

```
function string:replace(pattern, replace_string, ...)
   return (self:gsub(
      pattern:gsub("%p","%%%0"), 
      replace_string:gsub("%%","%%%%"), 
      ...
   ))
end
```

Example:

```
print(string.replace("25%", "%", " percent"))  --> 25 percent
print(("n>=0"):replace(">=", "≥"))             --> n≥0
s = "#01"; print(s:replace("#", ""))           --> 01
```