# string.gsub() on two paths not working

Tags: lua, relative-path, gsub

I looped in the directory tree of a "content" folder containing subdirectories and markdown files. Then I need to know the relative path of those markdowns from that "content" folder.

In bash script I would do something like that :

```
CONTENT_PATH="/home/myusr/apps/myapp/content"
file_path="/home/myusr/apps/myapp/content/file/pgp.md"

echo "${file_path#$CONTENT_PATH}"
# /file/pgp.md
```

So in Lua I didn't found something like that, so I've tried with `string.gsub()`:

```
print(string.gsub(file_path, CONTENT_PATH, ""))
-- /home/myusr/apps/myapp/content/file/pgp.md 0
```

But it's not working, it seems my CONTENT_PATH string does not match and I don't know why?

```
print(CONTENT_PATH)
-- /home/hs0ucy/_01_http/fakestache-lua/content

print(file_path)
-- /home/hs0ucy/_01_http/fakestache-lua/content/file/pgp.md
```

Thanks!

PS : I'm new to Lua.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the right thing, could you please edit your question to add the following output: `print(file_path)` `print(CONTENT_PATH)`

Comment: @adam_0 Done ... Those are the real outputs.

Comment: in Lua you can use: `print( file_path:match( CONTENT_PATH .. '(.+)' ))`

Comment: `gsub` interprets some punctuation characters as magic (hyphen is one of them).  You need [**plain** replacement function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45648295/1847592)

Answer (score 1):

From: [Lua string.gsub with a hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072601/lua-string-gsub-with-a-hyphen/29072637#29072637)

The hyphen is a special character in Lua, and needs to be escaped like so: `%-`.

I discovered this by slowly making `CONTENT_PATH` longer and longer until it was no longer working. Good ol' binary search!

EDIT: if you can't modify your `CONTENT_PATH` but you're sure that `file_path` has `CONTENT_PATH` in it:

```
contentPathLen = string.len(CONTENT_PATH)
print(string.sub(file_path, contentPathLen + 1))
-- Output: /file/pgp.md
```

Or if you need to verify that `file_path` starts with `CONTENT_PATH`:

```
base = string.sub(file_path, 0, contentPathLen)    
if base == CONTENT_PATH then
    print("file_path is under CONTENT_PATH")
end
```